# Custom event: Instance trash mob requirement for quest completion

Tags: events, world-of-warcraft, azerothcore, quest, anti-cheat

I'm scripting custom event where main requirement is to kill bosses in certain time and I need to prevent potential cheaters from using teleport hack inside of instance. Is there any way how I can add the trash mobs requirement in effective way ? I was thinking if there is any grouped identifier for those mobs which I can add into quest req.

Also I thought about invisible triggers which players would need to pass to progress in quest.

Another much simpler idea is just to add specific loot in trash loot and make player loot it but that is very inefficient and not comfy for players so that would be very last solution.

I also liked the idea of gathering souls like in [shadowmourne quest line](https://wotlkdb.com/?quest=24547) but there is a need to apply debuff from players to mobs so they trigger count on mob kill. It seems most advanced and would fit the idea perfectly but I'm not sure if it is doable in some effective way.

Thanks for any replies

Answer (score 0):

Allright so after some trial-error I managed to modify [mod-autobalance](https://github.com/azerothcore/mod-autobalance) so I apply [aura effect](https://wotlkdb.com/?spell=71169) on NPC stats update.

Fairly simple and now it allows me to add this aura to any mob I want for quest completion. And as quest completion requirement is set [this NPC](https://wotlkdb.com/?npc=38121).